# Running Oracle Data Pump Export on Linux

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-migration

I'm trying to do a data-only export using oracle data pump. I just wanted to make a test run on one single schema, however the result is not correct. I call expdp as follows:

```
./expdp user/password@x.x.x.x:1524/orcl1 DIRECTORY=EXPORTDIR DUMPFILE=orcl1_export.dmp LOGFILE=orcl1_export.log CONTENT=DATA_ONLY SCHEMAS=pfl_adm
```

Even I provided the username and password in the command line, I still get a prompt to log in as SYSDBA. Once I log in as SYSDBA, the export runs, however it seems that the tool is exporting another Oracle instance (we have several copies with the same schemas). The number of exported rows in the log file does not match with the number of rows in the database. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I just figured out that EXPDP exports another instance defined in tnsnames.ora. Are the command line arguments wrong?

Comment: The command is syntactically correct.

Comment: It seems like the tool uses another service name (orcl2) as default.. The exported rows match with this database instance.